# What's the difference between what I was hoping would happen? vs. What I was hoping that would happen?

Tags: conditional-constructions, relative-clauses, will-would, wh-questions, questions-v-relatives

1. The sentence "What I was hoping that would happen?" is possible? If possible, what is the function of that? Is it one of relative pronouns or what?
2. My understanding for "What I was hoping would happen?" is that the question type of an affirmative clause of the sentence.

Please let me know about the details of grammar related to tricky "that" thing.

Comment: Would you please give us more detail about the context(s)?

Answer (score 1):

"What I was hoping would happen" is a relative clause. It could be used in a sentence like this:
"This is what I was hoping would happen." or like this
"What I was hoping would happen actually happened."
That clause has a relative pronoun "what", that connects it to the main clause of the sentence.
Your example number 1 has both "what" and "that", and the example is not correct.

Example 2 isn't a question. A question form would have this word order:
"What was I hoping would happen?"

Comment: Thanks for your beautiful answer. What I was hoping *that would happen cannot be correct in a grammatical manner. Is it right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Really appreciated your answer. Have a good one!